# Make a BorderPane region go over another

Tags: javafx, javafx-8, scenebuilder

I've been trying for days and days now to get a BorderPane region go over another region...

The problem is as follow: My app is set in a BorderPane root, With:

- A header in its TOP region
- A menu in its LEFT region
- The content, depending on the page, in it's CENTER
- And an optional panel on its RIGHT region

That right region is the problem. It should appear/disappear when clicking on a "notification button" that is in the TOP region. So far so good. The thing is that the app doesn't use the RIGHT region, so I'm trying to make the RIGHT region that contains an AnchorPane go over the CENTER region. The normal state of the app is without the RIGHT region and I don't want to resize the whole app when opening the noitifications. Tried several things, such as:

- When clicking the notification button, send the CENTER part toBack() and set the RIGHT width to the 300 wanted pixels
- Sending the RIGHT region toFront()
- Sending the whole BorderPane toFront()

None of them work, as they all either not show, or resize the center part which I don't want. I'd like the RIGHT to float above the CENTER region when the notification menu is  showing.... Is there any way to do that? Or maybe another idea to trigger a container that would show above the CENTER part? Of course, I go design the panel in every CENTER pane and make it visible or not, but my app is about 15 different center windows so it would be really bad in terms of modifications...

Comment: Do you want the center part to resize when you resize the application window? This can be tricky :) Have you tried setting the ManagedProperty on the container in the CENTER to get it to stop responding to resize? Of course if the app must be able to resize you should look at doing the overlay outside of the borderpane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should not be trying to make the borderpane do this for you or you will end up with behavior you do not want like the center NOT resizing when the application is resized while the panel is visible.

Remember that JavaFX is really 3D. How about you try to wrap the BorderPane inside of an AnchorPane, GridPane or ScrollPane (whichever makes sense) instead of trying to get the right insert to do your thing.  e.g. add an ScrollPane (your Slider) to the containing AnchorPane and bring that to the front and anchor it's top, right and bottom.

This should give you a right-aligned ScrollPane on top of your borderpane.

Then of course if you want it to be fancy with an animated slide you can try this out : https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/1437374
or this:
http://blog.physalix.com/javafx2-borderpane-which-slides-in-and-out-on-command/

Here is a very rough example to show the idea:

```
public class JavaFXApplication2 extends Application {
ScrollPane slider;
AnchorPane root;

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    Button btn = new Button();
    btn.setText("Slide in");
    btn.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            root.getChildren().add(slider);
            AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(slider, 0.);
            AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(slider, 0.);
            AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(slider, 0.);
            slider.toFront();
        }
    });


    Label l = new Label();
    l.setText("Test Label to Show inside content");

    Label l2 = new Label();
    l2.setText("Peek-a-Boo");

    slider = new ScrollPane();
    slider.setStyle("-fx-border-color: orangered;");
    slider.setContent(l2);

    root = new AnchorPane();
    root.getChildren().add(btn);
    root.getChildren().add(l);

    AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(l, 0.);
    Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 250);

    primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World!");
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

}
```

Comment: Yeah, thank you for your answer! This is exactly what we call "think out of the box", when you go deep in your thinking you don't see the obvious anymore... That will definitly work, I just need to rework a few things to correctly adress the center then, but that's nothing. Still, if I may... When using a combobox, or a context menu, placed in say, the TOP part, it will extend above the CENTER part, as it is totally floating over the app. No way to mimic that behavior? I've even tried using them, but it's not usuable, as their natural system behavior is not ok for what I want

Comment: The code I posted does the same thing you describe I think ? It "totally floats" over the app from the right. You can of course do the same thing from any side, and the 2 links I included show how to animate it :)

Comment: Sure, I already did it about 10 minutes after you gave me the idea. It's a bit totally different in my case, but I'm confident with java so I made it in my flavor. As said, many thanks for the idea, it totally does what was wanted